# NuGet how to create nuspec file

Tags: command-line, command, nuget

I can't find it anywhere. How do i create a nuspec file of my project (VS2013). I tried "nuget spec" command but it doesn't work. I installed nuget command line and then i tried to run nuget.exe, it just blinks and exits.
So i can't enter the command anywhere i tried to use package manager console, cmd... But nothing works.

I wanna use NuGetter to create packages after build. But it needs those nuspec files of my project.

Any ideas please? :( I'm completly lost now.

Thanks.

Comment: This is documented on the [NuGet site](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package). Run NuGet.exe from an open command window to see its output.

Answer (score 2):

If you click nuget.exe it will blink and close it because it is an executable file not accepting any further input from the user.

For using nuget.exe you need to open in the command window where nuget.exe is physically stored (you can use enviroment variable also)  and follow with the command

C:/> nuget spec